# Division by zero error in image.php

Tags: php, images

Checking my error log on the server I continually see the error:

```
PHP Warning:  Division by zero in /public_html/wp-content/themes/sass-wordpress-bootstrap-master/image.php on line 95
```

Here is the code where that error is occurring:

```
$imgmeta = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $id );

                    // Convert the shutter speed retrieve from database to fraction
                          if ((1 / $imgmeta['image_meta']['shutter_speed']) > 1)
                          {
                             if ((number_format((1 / $imgmeta['image_meta']['shutter_speed']), 1)) == 1.3
                             or number_format((1 / $imgmeta['image_meta']['shutter_speed']), 1) == 1.5
                             or number_format((1 / $imgmeta['image_meta']['shutter_speed']), 1) == 1.6
                             or number_format((1 / $imgmeta['image_meta']['shutter_speed']), 1) == 2.5){
                                $pshutter = "1/" . number_format((1 / $imgmeta['image_meta']['shutter_speed']), 1, '.', '') . " second";
                             }
                             else{
                               $pshutter = "1/" . number_format((1 / $imgmeta['image_meta']['shutter_speed']), 0, '.', '') . " second";
                             }
                          }
                          else{
                             $pshutter = $imgmeta['image_meta']['shutter_speed'] . " seconds";
                           }
```

I'm not ever sure really when this would be called. Could a bot be triggering this error?

Comment: This seems to be a bug in respective theme, report it to its developers/support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

shutter speed is one of the exif data wordpress tries to extract from images when uploaded. If the image do not contain the info it will be zero, hence your division by zero error. Somewhere before that code you should check if the image even needs to go there. If it is not a photo then probably not.

Comment: Could is be as simple as creating a variable for shutter speed and checking to see if it is greater than zero? Something like: $imgShutter = $imgmeta['image_meta']['shutter_speed']; and then if ($imgShutter > 0) {

Comment: if one part of the logic do not make sense, there might be other that don't as well. Without knowing what the code does it is impossible to guess if filling this particular gap in the implementation will be enough. As rarst said, you should contact the theme author if it is not yours

Comment: Well, I pushed this out to my dev environment and it eliminated the error. I will contact the theme author and let them know. Thanks for your help on this!

Answer (score 0):

Even that you're sure that all your images have the 'shutter_speed' declared and more than 0 (although your error report is saying that some does not have), it's a good practice to validate it.

Try including a new parent if like this:

```
if ( isset($imgmeta['image_meta']['shutter_speed']) && (intval($imgmeta['image_meta']['shutter_speed'])>0) ) {
   ...
} else {
   $pshutter = 'unknow';
}
```

Comment: I don't even see a place to enter a value for shutter speed, so I really have no idea where it's coming from or why it's being referenced. I really have no use for it on this site.

Answer (score 0):

The error is being generated on image attachment pages, so this is most likely a bot. But I added a check before the shutter speed is converted to a fraction:

```
$imgmeta = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $id );
                        $imgShutter = $imgmeta['image_meta']['shutter_speed'];
                        // Convert the shutter speed retrieve from database to fraction

                        if ($imgShutter > 0) {

                          if ((1 / $imgmeta['image_meta']['shutter_speed']) > 1)
                          {
                             if ((number_format((1 / $imgmeta['image_meta']['shutter_speed']), 1)) == 1.3
                             or number_format((1 / $imgmeta['image_meta']['shutter_speed']), 1) == 1.5
                             or number_format((1 / $imgmeta['image_meta']['shutter_speed']), 1) == 1.6
                             or number_format((1 / $imgmeta['image_meta']['shutter_speed']), 1) == 2.5){
                                $pshutter = "1/" . number_format((1 / $imgmeta['image_meta']['shutter_speed']), 1, '.', '') . " second";
                             }
                             else{
                               $pshutter = "1/" . number_format((1 / $imgmeta['image_meta']['shutter_speed']), 0, '.', '') . " second";
                             }
                          }
                          else{
                             $pshutter = $imgmeta['image_meta']['shutter_speed'] . " seconds";
                           }
                        }
```